# How can i use complex direct query instead of activerecord in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, rails-activerecord

I have one rails application, which has one function that read values from database using active-record like this way

```
def get_all_products
 products = Product.for_locations(location_id)
 products.includes(:a, { b: [:c]}, {d: [:e]}, :f).each do |product|  
   product_forms = product.product_forms.sort_by{ |a| a[:sequence_no] } 
   .......
   .......
 end
end
```

this above function will take some time to process so this running as a background job. Now i would like to move this portion to a separate rails API application, so that will process and put that data in database, but this new application doesn't have any models and all, so how can i use this same function get_all_products in new rails API application, there i can't use active-record to get the data because there is no model, and even if i use direct query, its bit complicated, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You should use your `database-adapater` gem and probably, try to `establish connection` with the database and read the table and data from it.

Answer (score 2):

What I meant is you need to do something like this
    You need to establish connection first

```
connect = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'mysql2',
  :host => "localhost",
  :database => 'local_db'
)

sql_query = "your_query"
query_result = connect.connection.execute(sql_query)
query_result.to_a
```

Comment: Yes this way we can do, but my sql query is complex and that depends on so many other tables, more joins, sort, group... when we use active-record we can take the associated models from that active record object and we can do loop whatever we want, so is there anything in same way?

Comment: @django Build your query in the Rails console then throw a `to_sql` call on it to see the SQL that you end up building, then feed that to `connection.execute`.